# WCF service client times out in 1 minute even though SendTimeout is larger

Tags: wcf, timeout

On the client, my binding is configured like this:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_Mine" 
         sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="33554432" messageEncoding="Mtom">
     <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

But my service call times out in about 1 minute, and in the message it says that the timeout setting was 10 minutes, which I should increase. So it knows the right setting, and still times out after 1 minute.

I suppose that the problem is on the client side, as I have other clients which can call this same service without problems. The difference is their physical location and their internet provider.

Here are the exception details, unfortunately with the messages in Hungarian (there is a localized version of Windows at the client):

> 1) Exception Information
>
> ---
>
> Exception Type: System.TimeoutException
>   Message: A válaszra váró kérelemcsatorna túllépte az idokorlátot(00:10:00). Növelje a kérelem hívásának átadandó idokorlátértéket vagy a kötés SendTimeout értékét.A muvelet számára lefoglalt ido valószínuleg egy hosszabb idokorlát része volt.
>   Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
>   HelpLink: NULL
>   Source: mscorlib
>   HResult: -2146233083
>
> StackTrace Information
>
> ---
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at[0]: 
>      a következo helyen: System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      a következo helyen: System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      a következo helyen: Cosys.MagComm.Service.MagCommWS.MagComm.TransferPackage2(Byte[] credentials, String clientVersion, Int32 previousPackageId, Byte[] data)
>      a következo helyen: Cosys.MagComm.Service.JobSynchronComm.communicate(MagCommDataLayer dl, MagCommClient magCommProxy, Boolean skipPrices, NameValueCollection execInfo)
>      a következo helyen: Cosys.MagComm.Service.JobSynchronComm.Execute()
>
> 2) Exception Information
>
> ---
>
> Exception Type: System.TimeoutException
>   Message: A(z) „http://intranet-server/MagComm/MagComm.svc” felé irányuló HTTP-kérelem túllépte az engedélyezett 00:10:00 idokorlátot. A jelen muvelethez engedélyezett ido egy hosszabb idotúllépési intervallum része lehetett.
>   Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: System.Net.HttpWebResponse ProcessGetResponseWebException(System.Net.WebException, System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpAbortReason)
>   HelpLink: NULL
>   Source: System.ServiceModel
>   HResult: -2146233083
>
> StackTrace Information
>
> ---
>
> a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> 3) Exception Information
>
> ---
>
> Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
>   Status: Timeout
>   Response: NULL
>   Message: A kérelmet megszakították: Idotúllépés történt a muvelet végrehajtása során.
>   Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()
>   HelpLink: NULL
>   Source: System
>   HResult: -2146233079
>
> StackTrace Information
>
> ---
>
> a következo helyen: System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      a következo helyen: System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)|

Comment: What makes you think it's the send timeout that is failing?  Could it be a timeout on the service side?  Post the complete error message (plus any inner exception message).

Comment: Apparently the problem is with the underlying networking. I'm still investigating the issue...

Comment: The problem was network related. When the server was accessed through OpenVPN via an ADSL connection, in some cases it timed out even in 10 seconds. However there were no such problems when the server was accessed directly on the internet. (I have no further information on the OpenVPN version and settings being used.)